# Evaluate duration from raw audio array data of sound fragment

Tags: javascript, audio, buffer, duration, pcm

How to evaluate duration of sound fragment from raw array data?

I get raw data from microphone and I know the *sample rate* and the number of channels. I need mathematical formula to calculate the duration of this audio fragment.

I found out this:

```
1000 * bytesLength / 4 / rate_hz
```

But I think it's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salient factors balancing off quality against resource demands for raw audio in PCM format :

```
 Attribute     Typical Values
____________  _________________
bit_depth     16 bits per sample (8 bits per byte)        ... higher the better
num_channels  2 for stereo (or 1 for mono), lets use stereo
sample_rate   44100 samples per second (CD quality audio) ... higher the better
```

This formula expresses relationship between above variables :

```
storage_in_bytes / second == num_channels * sample_rate * bit_depth / 8
```

solving for seconds : (here is the equation you ask for)

```
duration in seconds = storage_in_bytes/(num_channels * sample_rate * (bit_depth/8))
```

plugging in using above variables we need to supply either storage_in_bytes or duration in seconds, so if

```
storage_in_bytes = 2 mb = 2097152 bytes
```

then we get

```
duration = 2097152/(2 * 44100 * (16/8)) = 11.89 seconds
```

Comment: In your first equation `bit_depth` was divided by `2` but in the next equation (the one you say the OP is asking for) the `2` is gone. Could you explain why is that?

Comment: 8 bits per 1 byte ... so bit depth of 16 bits == (16 bits / 8 ) bytes == 2 bytes per sample ... good catch now fixed